# PHP Date modify updating other variables

Tags: php, datetime

Trying to reduce 1 month from xyz date variable and store in different variable, why xyz variable is also impacted?

```
$timestamp = time();
$int_last_date = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Asia/Calcutta')); //first argument "must" be a string
$int_last_date->setTimestamp($timestamp); //adjust the object to correct timestamp
$int_last_date->format('Y-m-d');


print_r($int_last_date);
$int_from_date = $int_last_date;
$int_from_date = $int_from_date->modify('-1 month');
$int_from_date->format('Y-m-d');
print_r($int_last_date);
```

**Output:**

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2023-12-10 12:26:55.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Asia/Calcutta
)
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2023-11-10 12:26:55.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Asia/Calcutta
)
```

Expectation: `$int_last_date` should be same always